# GET variables with Jade in Django templates

Tags: python, django, pug

I use Jade (pyjade) with my Django project. For now I need to use `static` template tag with GET variable specified - something like following: `link(rel="shortcut icon", href="{% static 'images/favicon.ico?v=1' %}")`. But I get `/static/images/favicon.ico%3Fv%3D1` instead of `/static/images/favicon.ico?v=1`
Why it happens and how can I fix this?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You could try `href="{% static 'images/favicon.ico' %}"?v=1'`

Comment: Yes, it works, but GET variables generated by custom `static` tag. Maybe it's wrong way to add additional variables?